# ASPX files sometimes readonly when debugging in Visual Studio 2010 Premium

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net

I'm running Visual Studio 2010 Premium on a Vista 32-bit machine and I've noticed that sometimes when I'm debugging a website project I can't edit an aspx file. If I close the file and open it again then I can edit it. Has anyone else encountered this problem? The only extensions I have installed are the VS Productivity Power Tools and Power Commands.

Comment: What source control are you using?  Do you have Visual Source Safe, Team Foundation Server, Visual SVN, etc?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. We're using TFS. I haven't noticed this problem in recent weeks and in that time there were a few update for the Power Tools add-on, so I suspect that the problem may have been there.

Comment: Check:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450617/editing-aspx-ascx-files-randomly-disabled-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 0):

I also experience this problem (using Windows 7 or XP). This happens when:

1. I don't already have the .aspx file open in Visual Studio 2010
2. I am running the web app in debug mode

The file lock happens when I open and then try to edit an .aspx page (e.g. to tweak a bit of HTML) that I am currently viewing via a web browser when running the app in debug mode.

I've yet to find a solution for this problem however as a workaround I use "Browse With..." (Right click in Solution Explorer) to load and view the page(s) when I'm making HTML refinements. You can't debug code but it doesn't lock the files.